How to use different package name for react-native project
when i try to release my app on google play store this error show up ( https://ibb.co/6mJnn2m ) how to fix this. i used react-native to develop the project
i tried replacing all the places that used 'WheelbarrowProductionnew' to new name but then its throw errors when compiling
https://ibb.co/h9qK4tG
